# Door to AC unit causing pressure change?

Tags: hvac

Found water in the bottom of my AC unit inside. When I remove the bottom door the water will run back to the drain. But when I put the door back on, the water is being sucked down by the motor.  There is water on top of the motor and all around it. Can't leave the door off because the unit freezes. I have vaccumed to check for blockages and cleaned the coils

Comment: Sounds like your condensate drain line may be partially blocked. Is the door you are referring to the panel that exposes the side of the evaporator coil?

Comment: It's obvious, but check your return air for blockages including all filters.

Comment: Are you opening that door when it is running? Because it sounds as if the change in air flow is pulling the water back (again, possibly because of blockage). if so, turn it off before removing that cover.